# Does "+X +X until end of turn." effects remain on creatures in the graveyard and/or exiled until end of turn?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I use [Culling the Weak](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Culling%20the%20Weak) to sacrifice 4 creatures for 16 black mana, then use 15 of that mana on [Whispering Shade](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Whispering%20Shade) to make it stronger, can I then sacrifice them to get 5 mana for [Living Death](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Living%20Death) to bring all my creatures back with [Whispering Shade](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Whispering%20Shade)  being a 16/16?

Comment: **No.** Creatures only exist on the battlfield. When Whispering Shade is in the graveyard, it is a creature card. When Living Death returns the card to the battlefield it is a new object with no knowledge of its previous existance.

Comment: What is "them" in "can I then sacrifice them"?

Comment: I think 'them' refers to his Whispering Shade. Sacrificing 5 creatures with Culling the Weak would be problematic, as you need to cast it 5 times.

Comment: There seems to be a hefty amount of misunderstanding of the game rules in this question.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, with a single Culling the Weak, you can only sacrifice a single creature, not as many as you like. If you could use it multiple times, it would explicitly say so in the text. (Be sure to check the [text in the Oracle](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=6085) rather than the text on the physical card.) You can use Living Shade's ability as often as you like, but there is a difference between a one-shot spell effect and an activated ability.

Secondly, once you cast CtW, you cannot cast another spell (Living Death) and then continue sacrificing to CtW, because CtW has resolved, is in the graveyard, and its effect is over.

Thirdly, if you activate Living Shade's ability to make it stronger, then sacrifice it, then bring it back into play from the graveyard, it will be a completely new Living Shade with no "memory" of its previous existence, and thus will be 1/1.

Comment: +1 Spot on, it even say's you cannot sacrifice more than one creature in the rulings http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=6085